# Grouping array by sequencial date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This is more of a brains storm question
I would like to run something like

Student Model

```
id
name
age
so on...
```

GameStatus Model

```
id
game_id
student_id
status
created_at
```

Student has many game_statuses.
so every time a student opens a game it is added to the game_status model

I want to send little messages like... `Congratulation! You have completed 5 challenges in a row.`

So the marks are 5, 10, 15, 20 and 30.

It's pretty simple till here. I just loop through students and then loop through their game_statuses and if the count comes up to one of those marks I'll send a message.

But I want to make sure they hit those marks in a row.

As in 5 in the last five days or 10 in the last 10 days not broken.
So 3 times the week after last 1 time last week and 1 time this week will return 5 but it should not trigger the reward.

I was thinking of looking into the created_at date and check if they are in a array of dates such as [today, today -1, today -2, today -3, today -4]

```
@student = Student.find(param[:id])
@games = @student.game_statuses
total_games = []
for game in @games do
  if game.status = 'completed'
    total_games += game.id
  end
end
return total_games.count
```

Would it be possible to achieve this in a more elegant way?

Comment: Is there a question? A problem? Or are you asking us how to write your code?

Comment: this `if game.status = 'completed'` is alwais true. use `==`

Comment: @theTinMan did you read the post??? I started saying it was a brainstorming and I actually put something I think it might work. I was asking for an opinion. Is this clear enough for you now?

Comment: @LukasBaliak good catch... Thanks

Comment: @Marrento, Stack Overflow specifically says questions soliciting opinions are off-topic: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." While you might not like that, understand that Stack Overflow is a site for specific questions and answers. Ask a question when you have a specific problem once you have settled on the path you want to take.